# Find a condition for being the $f$ Gateaux differentiable at $0$, and that, consequently,the derivative of Gateaux is not necesarily linear map

Tags: analysis, gateaux-derivative

Show that the derivative of Gateaux exists, and is the linear map, if $f$ is differentiable with the ordinary meaning.If $f:R^n \to R$ with $$f(x)={g(x)\over h(x)}$$ where $g,h \in C^{\infty}(R^n)$,with $g(0)=h(0)=0$ but $h(x) \neq 0$ when $x \in U/\{0\}$ for some open area $U$ of $0$,Find a necessary and sufficient condition for being the $f$ Gateaux differentiable at $0$, and that, consequently,the derivative of Gateaux is not necessarily linear map.

Could anyone help me(hints and ideas) how to find this condition the second part of this problem?

Comment: These are two (rather loosely related) questions. Could you reformat your question to make it clear or post the second question as a new question?

Comment: You may start with the [two-dimensional example in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative#Linearity_and_continuity) to see the problem with linearity.